# Evolving With Realistic Freezing Powers

Tags: internal-consistency, biology

I've been getting nowhere myself on this.
My goal is to create a human or humanoid that absorbs heat to survive. As a result this can quickly freeze things solid. I need a way to make this, for lack of a better term, 'cryokinesis' (no tech or magic) in a way that could freeze someone solid without killing them or having them suffocate under the ice. My thinking was to have them somehow placed in suspended animation, that way they would not be functioning enough to break the ice, and still be alive.
But how would the ice form? How would the freezing be done? What would the biology of the human/humanoid need to be? (keep in mind that this being is still related to humans if not completely homo sapien. No aliens or monsters.)

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Are you looking for an active or passive method?

Comment: If by 'active' you mean 'willfully done' and by 'passive' 'constantly active,' then I would say active. But if it can only be done passively, then I would still accept it.

Comment: I've been thinking about this, but I can't come up with anything that results in a creature evenly remotely related to humans.

Comment: In general, I can't seem to find ANY mythical examples of a creature related to the cold, except for the Yeti which just lives in a cold place. And the frost giants, which again are magical, and I think they went extinct in the mythology.  Is it just that nobody on earth has considered such? In all history?  There's not even a deity relevant to it.

Comment: [Jack Frost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Frost), [Yuki-onna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuki-onna), and [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_legendary_creatures_by_type#Polar.2C_ice.2C_and_Winter) suggest there are examples.

Comment: "What would the biology of the human/humanoid need to be?" This isn't biologically/physically plausible.  It would require an incredibly powerful active cooling system in order to absorb enough heat to quickly freeze a person.  This would require a fantastic amount of energy to power, far far more than the energy required to simply generate the needed heat.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pump_and_refrigeration_cycle

Comment: So what you're saying is that freezing, even in a fictional example, is implausible. Hmm. What if the creature in question didn't generate heat itself? I think what we may need to start with is some sort of endothermic reaction that would draw away heat.  Now, in regards to what starts this reaction and where the heat goes, I'm uncertain. Perhaps it needs to absorb heat to survive?

Comment: Alas @Frostfyre but the list mainly speaks of simply cold climate creatures. Despite that, I still find it helpful. I could use these myths in other stories, but for now, we must figure this enigma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally heat moves from warm to cold.  To freeze something, it would have to be even colder already.

We know that things can be made colder through the consumption of energy. A home air conditioner or refrigerator does that.

There are mundane (to us; how our technology works) and exotic ways to [accomplish refrigeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pump_and_refrigeration_cycle).  Let's suppose that a living process manages to achieve it: it would be different from technology we are used to. You can imagine one metabolic process producing chemicals that are "used" elsewhere and cause an endothermic reaction.  That's obviously possible and rather simple. I expect a naturally evolved system to be more like chloroplasts: nanotechnology exploiting the subtitles of quantum mechanics to be far more efficient at the job.

Anyway, a life form *could plausibly* develop refrigeration.  Why? Maybe it's initially a side-effect of other processes. Maybe some enzymes or other metabolism works better at a colder temperature.  Maybe this allows the organism to forage in hydrothermal vents.

With such a thing in biology's toolkit, it might end up being used as a defense.  How about a venom that causes a freezing reaction? I don't think it could be powerful enough. How about storing liquid nitrogen and spraying it? Ice-breathing as opposed to fire-breathing!

---

Now freezing someone solid without killing him, by any means, just would not work. That's really a different idea than having an organism that can make things freeze.

Comment: I like the idea of chloroplasts that work on heat, but I was hoping the victim would live. Could a humanoid creature, in the sense that you could mistake it as a human, evolve a form of toxin that produces not only endothermic reactions (how?) but also produce ice-nucleating proteins that allow ice to form at higher temperatures (how?)? If so, then what would a realistic effect be? How would it be delivered? Perhaps it is produced by special separate glands like a toad's poison and frost over things by way of deposition (separate glands because I don't want the creature to 'sweat' it out)?

Comment: No. You don't get ice at higher temperature.

Comment: I wanted the creature to place people within ice without killing them. So what you mean is that all real and fictional laws are saying 'No to that, sir'?

Comment: The manner in which they are put into ice will not change the fact that it's fatal.  Consider a stasis-like effect other than a block of ice?

Comment: Indeed. Hypothermia, frostbite, and asphyxiation would arise within a block of ice. I have recently heard of using cold temperatures to place bodies in stasis. If they would still die under the ice, despite the cold putting them in some sort of suspended animation, then I'll just need to avoid complete frosting over. Due to the stasis keeping them motionless for a while, they wouldn't _need_ to be completely iced over, would they?

Comment: @JDłulgosz , Luck is on my side! I have recently encountered the theoretical concept of thermosynthesis, thought of as a precursor to photosynthesis. Biothermosynthesis consists of an organism draining heat from its environment as its energy source, rather then use light. Do you think that I could say that this humanoid organism evolved from extraterrestrial life into its current earth-bound form, and freezes anything in close proximity by draining heat to metabolize?

Comment: No, it would cost energy to be colder than the environment.  The ability to manipulate heat might be related to thermosynthetic metabolisms at the base of the food chain, or not. After all, bioluminescence has nothing to do with photosynthesis.  **but** a cold lure could be used by a preditor of thermosynthetic life.

Comment: Cost energy? It's constantly absorbing energy. The creature would utilize the heat energy in synthesizing glucose, like plants can do with chemicals or light. If the rate of absorption is high enough, the creature would easily induce freezing in nearby moisture. Despite this, if it was outside it couldn't possibly freeze over a great distance, but if it maintained close proximity to someone, it could induce hypothermia and frostbite quickly. Granted, this creature would need to have evolved from some seriously alien life to develop an ability like this, but it sounds reasonable.

Comment: absorbing energy:  in this universe, heat flows from hotter to colder objects.  You need to *find* hot and cold sinks to exploit a difference from.  Creating cold consumes energy, and makes it even hotter elsewhere.  So a creature evolved to extract energy from the difference between a hotspring and surrounding glacier, for example, would not naturally have freezing powers.

Comment: So there's nothing? Nothing that would allow the creature to draw the heat away without magic?

Comment: Right. Since this is tagged [tag:reality-check], you need something colder than the thing you want to freeze. Refrigeration requires energy to perform.  You can get more exotic than the normal meaning of "colder" but the principal holds: you need an entropy sink and power input.

Comment: Hmm... using 'reality-check' in the sense that it _could_ happen, how would some life form evolve on earth in a way that it draws on radiated heat for energy? If heat is being used as the source of energy for synthesis, it stands to reason that the creature becomes colder as this happens.

Comment: @Anonymía post that as a new Question.  You have a nice concise phasing already.  Add in your notes about thermosynthesis (with any links you already have).  I think it will be well received.  Suggest [tag:reality-check] and [tag:science-based] tags.  Though not *radiated* energy; the related discussion is on exploiting the difference between hot and cold regions.  "radiated heat" simply means plants that use IR for photosynthesis.